# The Origin of the Jacobian

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In what work did Jacobi introduce the jacobian, and what was his motivation for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the motivation, but it was introduced in his article *[Ueber die Functionaldeterminanten](https://archive.org/download/ueberdiefunction00jacouoft/ueberdiefunction00jacouoft.pdf)* (Journal für die reine und angewandte mathematik, bd. 22, 1841). However, Jacobians had already been studied by Cauchy in 1815.

Comment: The motivation is described at length in the article of Stackel, in the same file that you linked. It follows Jacobi's article.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thank you. I failed to notice it.

Comment: Was Jacobi aware of Cauchy's use of jacobians?

Comment: @user109871 He doesn't seem to mention Cauchy in his article.